# Svelte Pass Nested Store as a Prop

Tags: svelte

Trying to iterate through store that has been setup as `writable` map where one of the values is also a `writable` map. [Repl is here](https://svelte.dev/repl/3eb24669b26e45c689f25426bdffebe3?version=3.59.1). Error messages are `collection` is not a store with a subscribe method or Uncaught TypeError: store.subscribe is not a function.

store.js

```
import {writable} from "svelte/store";


export const nestedStore = writable({
    123456: {
        title: "First Item in Collection (no children)",
        children: writable({})
    },
    234567: {
        title: "Second Item in Collection (2 children)",
        children: writable({
            7890: {
                title: "Second Item Child 1"
            },
            7891: {
                title: "Second Item Child 2"
            }
        })
    },
    345678: {
        title: "Third Item in Collection",
        children: writable({})
    }
});
```

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import { onDestroy } from "svelte";
    import {nestedStore} from "./store";

    import NestedCollection from "./NestedCollection.svelte";
    

</script>

{#each Object.entries($nestedStore) as [collectionId, collection] (collectionId)}
    <h1>{collectionId}</h1>
    <NestedCollection bind:collection={collection} />
{/each}
```

NestedCollection.svelte

```
<script>
    export let collection;

</script>

<li>{collection.title}</li>
{#if Object.keys($collection.children).length }
    <ul>
        {#each Object.entries($collection.children) as [childId, child] (childId)}
            <svelte:self collection={child} />
        {/each}
    </ul>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collection` is not a store, `children` is, and there currently is no syntax to subscribe to stores that are properties of other objects. Your code (`$collection.children`) is being interpreted as `collection` being a store, which is not the case.

You would have to create another component, pass `collection.children` to it, then you can use something like `$children` in said component. Extracting `children` to, e.g. a `@const` value, will *not* work. That being the case, I would not recommend using nested stores unless absolutely neccesssary.

([Relevant issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4079))